# What Rogue class features can be used in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, multi-classing, rogue, wild-shape

This is a question about what Rogue class features are available in Wild Shape, for a druid/rogue multi-class character.

In the *Player's Handbook* it states that class features are usable in Wild Shape as long as the beast is able to carry out the tasks.

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new
>   form is physically capable of doing so.
>
> (PHB, p.67)

This question answers the possible use of **Expertise** in Wild Shape:
[Can a multiclassed druid/rogue benefit from Expertise while in Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145676/can-a-multiclassed-druid-rogue-benefit-from-expertise-while-in-wild-shape)

The maximum level available to a player multi-classing as a Druid/Rogue would be would be Druid L2 / Rogue L18, because the ability to Wild Shape becomes available to a druid at level 2. So, the answer does not need to include any Rogue abilities at higher levels.

What class features for a rogue would still be active in wild shape?

Comment: Related: "[Can a multiclassed Lore bard/druid use the Cutting Words feature while in Wild Shape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165244)" and "[Can a multiclassed bard/druid use the Bardic Inspiration feature while in Wild Shape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165238)" and "[Can you use Bladesong while you’re Wildshaped and Vice-Versa](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153550)" and "[Does a Monk/Druid multiclass character's Unarmored Movement add to their speed while in Wild Shape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83477)"

Comment: Heavily related: "[Do Rogue abilities function in wild-shaped beast forms?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127854)"

Comment: @NautArch - thanks, that's helpful. I hadn't thought of that. I will work on how to tidy this up and separate it, and will acknowledge the answer that has been provided too.

Comment: @NautArch Thank you - that was very helpful. I've updated the question with the level limits and have completed an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the PHB, a character who uses Wild Shape can benefit from your class features (e.g. multi-classing into Rogue too) as long as "the new
form is physically capable of doing so". In the answers below, I have only included features available to a Rogue up to level 18.

I think most of the core Rogue advancement features would work as usual:

- **Expertise**  - works as normal (you retain all skill and saving throw proficiencies in beast form; if the beast's bonus is higher use that one instead PHB p.67)
- **Cunning Action**  - works as normal (nothing preventing a beast from using its bonus action to Dash, Disengage or Hide; or Aim included in *Unearthed Arcana: Class Feature Variants*)
- **Uncanny Dodge** - works as normal (nothing preventing a beast from using a reaction or benefiting from damage reduction)
- **Evasion**  - works as normal (nothing preventing a beast from benefiting from the damage reduction for a damage source with an area-of-effect)
- **Reliable Talent** - works as normal (you retain all skill and saving throw proficiencies in beast form; if the beast's bonus is higher use that one instead PHB p.67)
- **Blindsense** - works as normal (nothing preventing a beast from benefiting from *blindsense*. If the beast already has this feature, the benefits do *not* stack; use the sensory radius which reaches farthest)
- **Slippery Mind** - works as normal (you retain all skill and saving throw proficiencies in beast form; if the beast's bonus is higher use that one instead PHB p.67)
- **Elusive**  - works as normal (a beast can benefit from attack rolls not having advantage against it)

The exceptions would be:

- **Thieve's Cant**: Obviously reading or deciphering something would be possible in most scenarios, but *not* conveying something back.
- **Sneak Attack**: is out of the question in most cases because "the attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon" (PHB, p.96). The possible exception could be wildshaping into an Ape (MM, p.317)  as they do have a Rock ranged attack; possibly at the DM's discretion an Ape could wield a weapon with the *finesse* descriptor and still be able to use Sneak Attack. (see: [Can a druid in Ape wildshape use weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-a-druid-in-ape-wildshape-use-weapons))

From the Roguish Archetypes in the *Player's Handbook* and *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, this is what I gather:

**THIEF:**

- **Fast Hands** - not likely to work (most beasts are not able to use, so it would not be possible to use Cunning Action and Thieves' Tools to disarm a trap or open a lock; might be possible in Ape form at the DM's discretion)
- **Second-Story Work** - works as normal (if the wildshape can climb, then climbing does not cost any extra movement)
- **Supreme Sneak** - works as normal (a beast can benefit from having advantage on a Dexterity (Stealth) check)
- **Use Magic Device** - may work sometimes at DM's discretion (see: [Can a familiar attune and wear or use a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107328/can-a-familiar-attune-and-wear-or-use-a-magic-item))
- **Thief's Reflexes** - works as normal (nothing prevents a beast from benefiting from an extra turn)

**ASSASSIN:**

- **Bonus Proficiencies** (disguise kit and poisoner's kit) - unlikely (it requires being able to use a kit, but may be possible in an Ape form at the DM's discretion)
- **Assassinate** - works as normal (a beast can benefit from advantage on an attack roll and can deal critical damage)
- **Infiltration Expertise** - irrelevant (a beast cannot pass for a humanoid identity)
- **Impostor** - irrelevant (a beast cannot mimic humanoid speech, writing or behaviour to create an indiscernible ruse)
- **Death Strike** - works as normal (a beast can attack a creature that is surprised)

**ARCANE TRICKSTER:**

- **Spellcasting** - does not work ("You can't cast spells" while wildshaped, but spells requiring *concentration* can continue to be active in Wild Shape as long as they are cast before transforming (PHB p.67). Druids do gain access to *Beast Spells* at 18th level and can cast spells that do not require a material component while wildshaped. However, that build is not possible in RAW as it would require 21 character levels: Druid 18; Rogue 3.)
- **Mage Hand Legerdemain** - only works if *Mage Hand* is cast before transformation
- **Magical Ambush** - does not work (you cannot cast spells in beast form)
- **Versatile Trickster** - only works if *Mage Hand* is cast before transformation
- **Spell Thief** - works in part (a beast can use a reaction so you can still force a creature to make a saving throw and negate the spell on a fail; you still know that spell for 8 hours and the creature is not able to cast that spell - however you would need to come out of Wild Shape to be able to cast the spell yourself)

**INQUISITIVE:**

- **Ear for Deceit** - works as normal (a beast can make Wisdom (Insight) check)
- **Eye for Detail** - works as normal (a beast can make a Wisdom (Perception) and/or Intelligence (Investigation) check)
- **Steady Eye** - works as normal (a beast can move up to half speed and benefit from advantage on Perception and Investigation checks)
- **Unerring Eye** - works as normal (a beast has senses and can benefit from this feature as long as it is not *blinded* or *deafened*)
- **Eye for Weakness** - does not work as requires Sneak Attack (possible exception as above, with an Ape's Rock attack)

**MASTERMIND:**

- **Master of Intrigue** - mostly not relevant (Most beast forms would not be able to use a disguise kit, forgery kit or a gaming set; at the DM's discretion it might be possible in Ape or other forms. The additional languages would remain active, but it would not be possible to communicate while in wildshaped. (PHB, p.67))
- **Master of Tactics** - works as normal (there is nothing preventing a beast from using a bonus action or the Help action)
- **Insightful Manipulator** - works as normal (a beast can observe a creature for a minute and thus benefit from this feature)
- **Misdirection** - works as normal (a beast can be the target of an attack and use its reaction)
- **Soul of Deceit** - works as normal (the druid/rogue will still have thoughts while wildshaped and thus be able to conceal these if so wished)

**SCOUT:**

- **Skirmisher** - works as normal (nothing prevents a beast from using its reaction and moving up to half its speed, so it can benefit from this feature)
- **Survivalist** - works as normal (nothing prevents a beast from benefiting from double proficiency bonuses when using Nature and Survival skills)
- **Superior Mobility** - works as normal, mostly (a beast can benefit from an increase of 10 feet to their walking, swimming or climbing speed; however, a creature's flying or burrowing speed does not benefit from this because *Superior Mobility* is explicit about the types of movement which are affected)
- **Ambush Master** - works as normal (a beast has an initiative roll and can make attacks)
- **Sudden Strike** - does not work as requires Sneak Attack (possible exception as above, with an Ape's Rock attack)

**SWASHBUCKLER:**

- **Fancy Footwork** - works as normal (a beast can make a melee attack and move in its turn, so it can benefit from this feature)
- **Rakish Audacity** - works in part (a best could grant itself an initiative bonus; but the additional way to use Sneak Attack would not work - the possible exception as above, with an Ape's Rock attack)
- **Panache** - situational (it works only if there is a "shared language", i.e. with another similar beast)
- **Elegant Maneuver** - works as normal (there is nothing preventing a beast from benefiting from advantage on Dexterity (Acrobatics) or Strength (Athletics) checks)
- **Master Duelist** - works as normal (a beast is able to make an attack roll, so it can benefit from this feature)

Although I have done **most of the footwork on this answer**, I would like to acknowledge Nautarch and Sarcastic Villain for their helpful suggestions and for contributing to the overall understanding of how Wild Shape features in this multi-class build.

Comment: In short: why? What is making you say each works or doesn't? Is your basis for answering each just your opinion on the capabilities of beasts?

Comment: @Someone_Evil  Hi, it's not opinion. I have gone through every Rogue feature and thought about how each Rogue feature applies when in Wild Shape - including variants where possible. If you have a doubt about a particular feature, just point it out and I would be happy to update/expand my answer, or investigate.

Comment: Distinguishing thought from opinion might be a matter of semantics. My point one the other hand is that I'm not seeing what those thoughts were, only their conclusion with no support to convince me that you are correct. Someone else posting a similar list saying all of them don't work would be equally supported, and my only way of choosing which is correct is the one I happen to agree with.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks @Someone_Evil - I will expand in brief each point as to why the class feature "works" or not. Thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 8):

Essentially, everything works unless it specifically says it doesn't, as per the rule you quoted in the question.

Sneak attack specifically doesn't work in most cases because it requires the use of a particular weapon, however if you transformed into something that could conceivably wield a finesse weapon such as an ape, sneak attack would apply under its normal conditions.

I would agree with [all of the deductions in your answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165675/what-rogue-class-features-can-be-used-in-wild-shape/165682#165682) aside from the Swashbuckler's Rakish Audacity and Panache.

My edited list is as follows:

Thief:

- Fast Hands - not likely to work, possibly as Ape at DM's discretion
- Second-Story Work - works as normal, unless the Wild Shape form cannot climb
- Supreme Sneak - works as normal
- Use Magic Device - not likely to work, but situational and at DM's discretion
- Thief's Reflexes - works as normal

Assassin:

- Bonus Proficiencies (disguise kit and poisoner's kit) - highly unlikely
- Assassinate - works as normal
- Infiltration Expertise - irrelevant
- Impostor - irrelevant
- Death Strike - works as normal

Arcane Trickster:

- Spellcasting - not possible in Wild Shape, but spells requiring concentration can continue to be active in Wild Shape if cast before transforming
- Mage Hand Legerdemain - only works if Mage Hand is cast before transformation
- Magical Ambush - does not work
- Versatile Trickster - only works if Mage Hand is cast before transformation
- Spell Thief - works, but would need to come out of Wild Shape to cast the spell

Inquisitive:

- Ear for Deceit - works as normal, unless beast is deaf
- Eye for Detail - works as normal
- Steady Eye - works as normal
- Unerring Eye - works as normal
- Eye for Weakness - works as normal if sneak attack can be triggered

Mastermind:

- Master of Intrigue - no use for disguise kit, forgery kit or gaming set; understanding the languages would remain active but would not be able to communicate in them while transformed
- Master of Tactics - works as normal
- Insightful Manipulator - works as normal
- Misdirection - works as normal
- Soul of Deceit - works as normal

Scout:

- Skirmisher - works as normal
- Survivalist - works as normal
- Superior Mobility - works as normal (except for flying speeds)
- Ambush Master - works as normal
- Sudden Strike - works as normal if Sneak Attack can be triggered

Swashbuckler:

- Fancy Footwork - works as normal
- Rakish Audacity - **see below**
- Panache - **see below**
- Elegant Maneuver - works as normal
- Master Duelist - works as normal

**My clarifications:**

- The initiative bonus from Rakish Audacity will always apply, and the
  alternative use of Sneak Attack would also apply if the other
  conditions of Sneak Attack could be met, namely the Sneak Attack's
  specific weapon requirements.
- Panache also functions under the condition stated:

  > The creature must be able to hear you, and the two of you must share a 
  >   language.

  If you have some means to speak whatever language though magic or
  otherwise, the ability will still function.

Obviously some very niche cases where these work, but I just wanted to point out that it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Sarcastic Villain Thank you for pointing out the features from Panache and Rakish Audacity. I have included this into a complete answer.

Comment: For some of the features you have justification for a feature working (or not working), but I would really like to see support for the rest of the features, so that they are not just based on your opinion about the nature/capabilities of beasts.